USB hub slows boot time significantly - what can I do?
I have a USB hub plugged into my laptop which is slowing down my boot times significantly. I cannot move this hub to a different port as it's on the only USB-C port I have. Here is part of the log:
[    8.801767]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3
[    8.801990] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   10.171754] psmouse serio1: Failed to deactivate mouse on isa0060/serio1: -71
[   10.270608] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
[   11.390841] input: PS/2 Generic Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
[   11.456781] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
[   23.914123] usb 1-4.2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   39.784994] usb 1-4.2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   39.967963] usb 1-4.2.3: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[   55.656997] usb 1-4.2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   71.528994] usb 1-4.2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   71.635291] usb 1-4.2-port3: attempt power cycle
[   72.230969] usb 1-4.2.3: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[   77.595057] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   83.226975] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   83.434969] usb 1-4.2.3: device not accepting address 14, error -62
[   83.435274] usb 1-4.2.3: WARN: invalid context state for evaluate context command.
[   83.511968] usb 1-4.2.3: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[   88.859070] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   94.491064] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   94.699963] usb 1-4.2.3: device not accepting address 15, error -62
[   94.700248] usb 1-4.2.3: WARN: invalid context state for evaluate context command.
[   94.700384] usb 1-4.2-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
[   95.784661] system76_acpi: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   95.784664] system76_acpi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   95.786460] system76: Model does not utilize this driver
[   95.844186] usbcore: registered new interface driver system76-io

Is there anything I can do on the software side of things to speed this up? I'd rather not unplug and replug it every time I boot up. Worth noting that if I unplug it while the computer is in the trenches dealing with it, it will more or less instantly get to the Gnome greeter; this USB hub alone is directly holding up the boot. It also starts functioning much faster (single-digit seconds) when plugged back in AFTER the Gnome greeter appears.
Unplugging and replugging is an option if there are no software solutions, but I have the programmer's soul, and would prefer to spend too much time on it once and then never deal with it again.
Edit: lsusb --tree:
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 10000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 5000M <-- is it this one???
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 12, If 0, Class=, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 13, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M

I'm not really sure what the device on port 3 actually is. It appears to be part of the hub itself from my testing but I don't know what part. I would guess it's maybe the HDMI as I know that does not work, but it might be usb-c, vga or sd/microsd as I have never tested any of those. I'm also not sure I'm interpreting the numbers right.
Edit: Apparently it is the USB ethernet adapter. Very much not something I expected as I know that it works and is relatively rock-solid.

what's attached to port 3? can you give us the output of lsusb --tree after it's booted, by editing your question to include that, please?

because whatever is attached to port 3 of the USB hub 4.2 on the first USB bus, that's simply broken.

maybe the GUI is hanging trying to probe a broken hdmi interface in the hub?  Maybe you can blacklist the device from the kernel command line?

@user10489 I'm seeing that I have to find the vendor and product ID for the device, but I don't know how to find that - the lsusb and lsusb --tree outputs are formatted very differently and I can't tell which device it is

r8152 is a USB-Ethernet adapter... do you have network boot enabled in your BIOS? And it's trying to probe that?

Or maybe the machine is hanging around trying to DHCP on that adapter and eventually timing out.

Add a -v to your lsusb -t and you'll get the IDs as well ...

Per your edit : "Apparently it is the USB ethernet adapter" . If you used a command or log inspection or some other debugging process to discover this, consider posting an answer. You can self-accept your answer (after 48 hrs) to gain valuable reputation points (and I will likely upvote too).

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110 - it's a power problem, not subject to a software fix.
